# Spring Security + Angular JS + CORS issue - Error XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/user. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

Tags: angularjs, spring-security, cors, spring-security-oauth2, oauth-2.0

Note: I have omitted http:// in some links as SO doesnt allow me to post more than 2 URLs yet.

I have an Angular UI served out of localhost:5000. I have REST APIs served out of localhost:8080. I authenticate on the REST API server using Facebook Oauth2. Subsequently, I want to access the /user endpoint on the server where I was authenticated.

For the example purpose here, I will refer to the spring sample in  github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2.git. I have modified the code for the github example.

I followed your blog post and added a filter as follows

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean corsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost");
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:5000");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The App is as-is in the spring sample in the github directory

```
package com.example;

import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.Filter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.ResourceServerProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoTokenServices;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.NestedConfigurationProperty;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientContext;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableAuthorizationServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableOAuth2Client;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@EnableOAuth2Client
@EnableAuthorizationServer
@Order(6)
public class SocialApplication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    OAuth2ClientContext oauth2ClientContext;

    @RequestMapping({ "/user", "/me" })
    public Map<String, String> user(Principal principal) {
        Map<String, String> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("name", principal.getName());
        return map;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/login**", "/webjars/**").permitAll().anyRequest()
                .authenticated().and().exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/")).and().logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll().and().csrf()
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()).and()
                .addFilterBefore(ssoFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/me").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean oauth2ClientFilterRegistration(OAuth2ClientContextFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(filter);
        registration.setOrder(-100);
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("github")
    public ClientResources github() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("facebook")
    public ClientResources facebook() {
        return new ClientResources();
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter() {
        CompositeFilter filter = new CompositeFilter();
        List<Filter> filters = new ArrayList<>();
        filters.add(ssoFilter(facebook(), "/login/facebook"));
        filters.add(ssoFilter(github(), "/login/github"));
        filter.setFilters(filters);
        return filter;
    }

    private Filter ssoFilter(ClientResources client, String path) {
        OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter = new OAuth2ClientAuthenticationProcessingFilter(
                path);
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(client.getClient(), oauth2ClientContext);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        UserInfoTokenServices tokenServices = new UserInfoTokenServices(client.getResource().getUserInfoUri(),
                client.getClient().getClientId());
        tokenServices.setRestTemplate(oAuth2RestTemplate);
        oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter.setTokenServices(tokenServices);
        return oAuth2ClientAuthenticationFilter;
    }

}

class ClientResources {

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails client = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();

    @NestedConfigurationProperty
    private ResourceServerProperties resource = new ResourceServerProperties();

    public AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public ResourceServerProperties getResource() {
        return resource;
    }
}
```

In Angular, the code is as follows. After authentication, I expect to get the user details from /user

```
$http.get("http://localhost/user").success(function(data) {
  if (data.name) {
    self.user = data.name;
    self.authenticated = true;
  } else {
    self.user = "N/A";
    self.authenticated = false;
  }
}).error(function() {
    self.user = "N/A";
    self.authenticated = false;
});
```

This gets executed after I am authenticated using Facebook's OAuth2.

I get an error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/user. Response for preflight is invalid (redirect)

as a 302 happens for the pre-flight OPTIONS request

Request for the get is as follows

```
OPTIONS
 /user HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Origin: http://localhost:5000
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, x-requested-with
Accept: */*
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:5000/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6,ms;q=0.4,hi;q=0.2
```

Response is

```
HTTP/1.1
 302
Set-Cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=8a4e7e55-25fb-4293-975d-19979b65327e;path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: http://localhost:8080/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 17 Nov 2016 14:32:35 GMT
```

The pom is as it is in the spring sample, except I changed the spring boot from 1.4.0.RELEASE to 1.4.1.RELEASE

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>angularjs</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
        <artifactId>webjars-locator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

After authentication, on another browser tab, if I access "localhost:8080/user" I get the right data back. So authentication has succeeded.

What am I missing?

thanks

Comment: Finally, got this working by setting   spring.filter-order: 50 (some high number), so that corsFilter appears before springSecurityFilterChain and OAuth2ClientContextFilter.

Comment: http://mtyurt.net/2015/07/15/spring-how-to-insert-a-filter-before-springsecurityfilterchain/ says that spring security chain was setting the order to 0 and that this is the recommended way to override this. This will explain why the bean.setOrder(0) was overridden.